# Entire function $f$ such that $f(n) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that there exists an entire function $f$ s.t. $f(n) = \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. (Using Weierstrass theorem or Mittag-Leffler theorem)

Is there any simple formula to express $f$? The value $\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$ comes from the residue of $\Gamma(z)$, so I guess that $f$ would be expressed in terms of $\Gamma(z)$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Take $f(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma}(z+1)e^{iz\pi}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing to try would be, writing $(-1)^n = \exp(i\pi n)$ and $n! = \Gamma(n+1)$.  But that fails because $\Gamma(-1) = \infty$.  However,
$f(z) := 1/\Gamma(z)$ is an entire function (removable singularities), so an answer is
$$
e^{i\pi x} f(x+1) = \frac{e^{i\pi x}}{\Gamma(x+1)}
$$
Once we have this, we can get other solutions by adding any entire function that vanishes on $\mathbb Z$.  Thus, adding anything of the form $(e^{2i\pi x}-1)G(x)$ with $G$ entire.